# Ionic 3 refer a new page in app module issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I generated a new page in ionic 3 using the generate command. When I try adding it to the app module it throws the following error,

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'NewTodo' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
```

Previously while using ionic 2.x I never added annotations manually. Any idea how I can resolve it?

**UPDATE**

**new-todo.ts** file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Data} from '../../providers/data';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-new-todo',
  templateUrl: 'new-todo.html',
})
class Todo { 
  public title: string; 
  public completed: boolean; 
  constructor() { 
    this.title = ''; 
    this.completed = false; 
  } 
}

export class NewTodo {
  todo: Todo;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public _data: Data,public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
    this.todo = new Todo();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad NewTodo');
  }

  save(){
    var key = this._data.save(this.todo);
    if(key){
      // console.log('saved');
      let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: '',
        duration: 3000
      });
      toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
        this.navCtrl.pop();
        console.log('toast dismissed');
      });
      // this.navCtrl.present(toast);
      toast.present();
    }
  }

}
```

**app-module.ts** file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { NewTodo } from '../pages/new-todo/new-todo';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import {Data} from '../providers/data';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
// AF2 Settings
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBiVsxqjSlsPpcHCzJi0anzInr2N9FLv5E",
  authDomain: "test-project-5f51f.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://test-project-5f51f.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "test-project-5f51f.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "341872568316"
};
// firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    NewTodo
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    NewTodo
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    [Data]
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**UPDATE-2**

**new-todo.module.ts** file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NewTodo } from './new-todo';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NewTodo,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forChild(NewTodo),
  ],
  exports: [
    NewTodo
  ]
})
export class NewTodoModule {}
```

Comment: is `NewTodo` declared as `IonicPage`? also is there new-todo.module.ts?

Comment: Yes, I got a new-todo.module.ts file. How can I declare it as IonicPage. I think the problem is that I'm using two classes inside new-todo.ts and angular is expecting me to declare NewTodo as a component. If that is the case, do you have any idea how I can declare it as a component?

Comment: Can you show the new-todo.module.ts file?

Comment: @suraj I have updated my question with 'new-todo.module.ts' file and I just noticed that "forChild()" shows an error like "Property 'forChild' does not exist on type 'typeof IonicModule'."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ionic 3. Each page is by default setup as a separate module in order to implement [lazy loading](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGokwMXPQItZmTHZQbTO4qwj_SQymFhRS_nJmiH0K3w/edit) of pages.

Your page will be declared in **new-todo.module.ts**.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        NewTodo
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(NewTodo)
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        NewTodo
    ]
})
```

Check out [IonicPageModule](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/IonicPageModule/) docs as well as [IonicPage](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/).

In your component  **new-todo.ts** page, add the `@IonicPage()` decorator above the component decorator.

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-new-todo',
  templateUrl: 'new-todo.html',
})
```

Also *remove all imports to this page outside of the page module.* Use the string `'NewTodo'` instead of the imported class when pushing the page in NavController.
You dont have to declare the page in **app.module.ts**

Comment: I have modified the code exactly like how you mentioned. But I still get this error "Error: No component factory found for NewTodo. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?" :(

Comment: have you imported the page anywhere?

Comment: Yes,  in home page to push data from home page to new-todo. If I didn't import NewTodo and push it as string like this 'NewTodo' it gives me the following error "Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: NewTodo"

Comment: you shouldnt import the page.. set as string. is your package.json similar to [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json)?

Comment: Exactly the same except "ionic-angular" which is "3.0.1".. I guess that shouldn't be a problem.. :(

Comment: try updating it.. there may have been a fix.. 3.x is new

Comment: Thanks @suraj, your guidance helped me understand ionic 3. Thanks for your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141419/discussion-between-gowtham-and-suraj).

Answer (score 1):

$ ionic generate creates a module for lazy-loading pages in ionic3

If you don’t want to take advantage of lazy loading use

```
$ ionic generate [type] [name] --no-module
```

// Do not generate an NgModule for the component

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/generate/

Answer (score 0):

In the declaration section of `NgModule` you have listed a class `'NewTodo'` which requires to be A component, or directive, or pipe. Either remove the class name or add corresponding declarator `@Pipe/@Directive/@Component`

Comment: Hi @Roman C, Thanks for your answer. But NewTodo is a class I have in new-todo.ts file and I'm trying to import it. I have updated my question with my new-todo.ts page and app.module.ts page. Thanks

Comment: I said `a class 'NewTodo'`.