# Ionic3: Is it necessary to declare pages and pages modules in app.module.ts

Tags: ionic3

I used to declare the pages and pages modules of my ionic app in app.module.ts.
However, I just removed all those declarations, and the app still works completely fine (tested in browser, not in mobile).
So I wonder if those declarations are necessary or not.

According to [this post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339695/ionic-3-refer-a-new-page-in-app-module-issue) it is not necessary to declare pages in app.module.ts, but it doesn't mention page modules.

My app.module.ts works like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

// imports
import { PageModule_view_raw } from '../pages/page1/page1.module';
import { PageModule_view_raw } from '../pages/page2/page2.module';
import { PageModule_view_raw } from '../pages/page3/page3.module';
import { Page1 } from '../pages/page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../pages/page2/page2';
import { Page3 } from '../pages/page3/page3';

import { SomeProvider } from '../providers/someprovider';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../components/components.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpModule,
    // pages modules
    PageModule1,
    PageModule2,
    PageModule3,
    // components
    ComponentsModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    // pages
    Page1,
    Page2,
    Page3,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    // providers
    SomeProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But it also works like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

// imports
import { SomeProvider } from '../providers/someprovider';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../components/components.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpModule,
    // components
    ComponentsModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    // providers
    SomeProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

On the other hand, if I don't declare ComponentsModule, then it won't work.
Are page modules fetched automatically? Is there any point in declaring them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to import page modules in the app module...
If you have used

```
IonicPageModule.forChild(PageName)
```

in your page module, it will be bootstrapped for navigation.

[Here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/module.ts#L488) is what it looks like:

```
export class IonicPageModule {

  static forChild(page: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: IonicPageModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: <any>LAZY_LOADED_TOKEN, useValue: page },
        { provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, useValue: page, multi: true },
      ]
    };
  }

}
```

> IonicPageModule is an [NgModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) that
>    bootstraps a child IonicPage in order to set up routing.

*On the other hand, if I don't declare ComponentsModule, then it won't work.*

This is because `ComponentsModule` will contain your angular components which are not set as lazy loaded pages. You need to ensure your app includes the components by importing the `ComponentsModule`.

Comment: Thanks for including the source of the `IonicPageModule.forChild(...)` method, and for such an excellent explanation!