# Ionic Giving Typescript error while Building

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hello i am trying to build android application for production using command `ionic cordova build android --prod`

The problem is that after running this code it is giving me this following typescript error.

```
    typescript error
    Type ContactPage in C:/Users/Akshay S. Shrivastav/Desktop/vidyotan_2k18/src/pages/contact/contact.ts is part
    of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in C:/Users/Akshay S.
    Shrivastav/Desktop/vidyotan_2k18/src/app/app.module.ts and ContactPageModule in C:/Users/Akshay S.
    Shrivastav/Desktop/vidyotan_2k18/src/pages/contact/contact.module.ts! Please consider moving ContactPage in
    C:/Users/Akshay S. Shrivastav/Desktop/vidyotan_2k18/src/pages/contact/contact.ts to a higher module that
    imports AppModule in C:/Users/Akshay S. Shrivastav/Desktop/vidyotan_2k18/src/app/app.module.ts and
    ContactPageModule in C:/Users/Akshay S.
    Shrivastav/Desktop/vidyotan_2k18/src/pages/contact/contact.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule
    that exports and includes ContactPage in C:/Users/Akshay S.
    Shrivastav/Desktop/vidyotan_2k18/src/pages/contact/contact.ts then import that NgModule in AppModule in
    C:/Users/Akshay S. Shrivastav/Desktop/vidyotan_2k18/src/app/app.module.ts and ContactPageModule in
    C:/Users/Akshay S. Shrivastav/Desktop/vidyotan_2k18/src/pages/contact/contact.module.ts.

    Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
        at C:\Users\Akshay S. Shrivastav\Desktop\vidyotan_2k18\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:237:55
        at step (C:\Users\Akshay S. Shrivastav\Desktop\vidyotan_2k18\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:32:23)
        at Object.next (C:\Users\Akshay S. Shrivastav\Desktop\vidyotan_2k18\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:13:53)
        at fulfilled (C:\Users\Akshay S. Shrivastav\Desktop\vidyotan_2k18\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:4:58)
```

This is my `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { EventsPage } from '../pages/events/events';
import { WorkshopsPage } from '../pages/workshops/workshops';
import { TeamPage } from '../pages/team/team';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { DeveloperPage } from '../pages/developer/developer';
import { WildcardPage } from '../pages/wildcard/wildcard';
// import { DetailsPage } from '../pages/details/details';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

rootPage: any = HomePage;

pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
  this.initializeApp();

  //menu navigators
  this.pages = [
    { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
    { title: 'Events', component: EventsPage },
    { title: 'Wildcard Entries', component: WildcardPage },
    { title: 'Workshops', component: WorkshopsPage },
    { title: 'Vidyotan Team', component: TeamPage },
    { title: 'Contact', component: ContactPage },
    { title: 'App Developer', component: DeveloperPage },
  ];

}

initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
    // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
    // this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#337ab7");
    this.splashScreen.hide();
  });
}

openPage(page) {
  // Reset the content nav to have just this page
  // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
  this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
}
}
```

This is my `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { EventsPage } from '../pages/events/events';
import { WorkshopsPage } from '../pages/workshops/workshops';
import { TeamPage } from '../pages/team/team';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { DeveloperPage } from '../pages/developer/developer';
import { DetailsPage } from '../pages/details/details';
import { WildcardPage } from '../pages/wildcard/wildcard';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    EventsPage,
    WorkshopsPage,
    TeamPage,
    ContactPage,
    DeveloperPage,
    DetailsPage,
    WildcardPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    EventsPage,
    WorkshopsPage,
    TeamPage,
    ContactPage,
    DeveloperPage,
    DetailsPage,
    WildcardPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is my `contact.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

    // import { Contact1Page } from '../contact/contact';

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-contact',
      templateUrl: 'contact.html',
    })
    export class ContactPage {

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
      }

      ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad ContactPage');
      }

    }
```

This is my `contact.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { ContactPage } from './contact';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        ContactPage,
      ],
      imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(ContactPage),
      ],
    })
    export class ContactPageModule {}
```

What might be the problem I am not able to get it. UI have done everything according to me I also searched through various forums but still the same error while building the app for a Production environment.

Please Help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: dont declare pages in app module if they are already in the declaration array of the page modules

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43340647/4826457

Comment: @SurajRao i am still not able to get it what to do as i am new to it its totally confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this issue several times as ionic says a specific page is part of two declarations one is our main app component declarations and the second is individual components modules.
So basically removing it from individual component.module.ts file works for me so try removing the page declaration from your contact.module.ts file

```
@NgModule({
  declarations : [
                     //keep this empty 
  ],
  imports : [
   .... 
  ]
```

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly instead i imported all modules and added in the imports section

Answer (score 1):

Remove "ContactsPage" from "declaration" and entry "components" in your "AppModule.ts" as it is already imported in "contact.module.ts"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare `ContactPage` in the `app.module.ts` file as it is already declared in the `contact.module.ts` file. So, you have to remove the `ContactPage` from **declarations** and  **entryComponents** in the `app.module.ts` file.